# Use ABB's SafeMove with ROS and the add_driver?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, abb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have searched for this and haven't found any information about it, and i hope this is the right place to ask this question.

I'm working on a project with 4 ABB robots that i will be controlling with ROS. For saftey reasons the robot supplier we are using is insisting in using ABB's SafeMove 1. They have never even heard about ROS.
I have a small ABB robot that i am using to test parts of our system atm, but am no able to get SafeMove for that, so won't be able to test my setup with the SafeMove setup until it gets to the install. Has anyone every come used SafeMove 1 in conjunction with ROS and the add_driver?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Dominik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372956/use-abb%27s-safemove-with-ros-and-the-add_driver?/) by [Dominik JBS](https://answers.ros.org/users/68781/dominik-jbs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First: I believe you mean [abb_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver), not `add_driver`, correct?

If so: pay attention to the [Status](http://wiki.ros.org/abb_driver#Status) section of that page (or the [same section in the readme](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_driver#status)): while usable, `abb_driver` is not feature complete, nor will it allow 100% use of the motion performance of your robots (due to the way it interfaces with the controller).

Focus has shifted to [abb_robot_driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/abb_robot_driver), which would be recommended to use, provided you have EGM licenses.

Having written that:

> They have never even heard about ROS.

I'm not surprised.

> I have a small ABB robot that i am using to test parts of our system atm, but am no able to get SafeMove for that, so won't be able to test my setup with the SafeMove setup until it gets to the install.

All available ROS drivers for ABB robots/controllers are compatible with RobotStudio. Can't you create a cell with a SafeMove enabled controller and simulate your setup?

> Has anyone every come used SafeMove 1 in conjunction with ROS and the add_driver?

Yes, I have.

Something to realise: `abb_driver` is a simple, user-level task program as far as the ABB controller is concerned. There is no difference in the level of access or control compared to some RAPID code you wrote yourself.

Consequently, SafeMove also doesn't care whether your're running your own RAPID program, `abb_driver` or something else entirely. It will just function as it always does, meaning it will stop execution of motions if/when they (appear to) go out of the configured safety-limits.

You'll just need to make sure those limits either:

1. correspond to whatever limits are specced by the `.urdf`s/`.xacro`s and/or MoveIt configuration pkgs you're using, or
2. update any `.urdf`s/`.xacro`s and/or MoveIt configuration pkgs you intend to use such that the limits in those files and/or packages correspond to whatever limits you've configured SafeMove with

The first will likely make no sense, safety-wise (as you'd still allow the robots to use 100% of their work envelope at 100% speed and acceleration). The second is most likely what you'll want/need to do.

There is no automated support for SafeMove in `abb_driver` (nor in `abb_robot_driver`).

It would be interesting to add though (as it would likely come down to extracting some information from the controller's configuration and updating a few configuration files on the ROS side). But it would also be out-of-scope for the driver(s) in a way: joint limits are part of the robot support and MoveIt configuration packages, not of the driver(s) (note: I'm referring to joint limit *specification*, enforcement is of course part of the responsibilities of drivers).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-01**:
PS: you've figured out [where to go](https://www.jasonbruges.com/art/#/where-do-we-go-from-here/)?

**Comment by [Dominik JBS](https://answers.ros.org/users/68781/dominik-jbs/) on 2021-03-04**:
Thanks so much for the extensive answer to my question and apologies for the late reply. I'm working on a few other projects at the moment as well, so haven't been on this for a few days.
This is all very good to know. I have a robot studio simulation of my setup, i will include SafeMove in that to test it. I actually wanted to try to use the abb_robot_driver with EGM for this, but since i have a working system with the abb_driver already, and time is limited i might just stick with that since it pretty much seems to work fine. But if i do get time i will give it a try.
cheers